# The directory is invalid. What is going wrong? copying file from source to destination

Tags: c#, file

So I am trying to copy a file from a source to a destination. I'm creating a windows form where i have buttons, source and destination. They are used to get a file and then get a desination. then another button is used to copy that file to the destination. when i click the destination, I get 'The directory name is invalid'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CopyDirectory
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    string file = "";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            //opens the file source & shows it in a label
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                int size = text.Length;
                string sfile = Path.GetFileName(file);
                lbl_sfile.Text = sfile; // for full location
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            //saves the file destination & shows it in a label

            //use file2 string to save file into destination

            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lbl_dfile.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Caluculate(int i)
    {
        double pow = Math.Pow(i, i);
    }

    private void bttn_savefile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //collect label text as strings
        string file2 = lbl_sfile.Text.ToString();
        string file3 = lbl_dfile.Text.ToString();

        string sourceDir = file;
        string backupDir = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

        Path.Combine(file2, Path.GetFileName(file3));

        string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg");
        string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt");

        // Copy text files.
        foreach (string f in txtList)
        {

            // Remove path from the file name.
            string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

            try
            {
                // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName));
            }

            // Catch exception if the file was already copied.
            catch (IOException copyError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
            }
        }


        // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
        progressBar1.Value = 10;

        progressBar1.Maximum = 100000;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        {
            Caluculate(j);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which exact line throws the error?  What are the runtime values of the variables on that line when it happens?

Comment: I'm guessing that the destination directory is invalid. As we don't know what the variables hold when the error occurs, that's probably the best you can expect.

Comment: @David string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt");

Comment: @KenWhite string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt");

Comment: That does not tell us what the value of `txtList` is after that assignment. This would be an excellent opportunity for you to learn to use the debugger to step through the code as it runs, so you can see exactly what it's doing and examine the contents of variables as the code executes.

Comment: @helloworld999: And what is the value of sourceDir?

Comment: @helloworld999 What is the value of `file` after its assignment `file = openFileDialog1.FileName;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for some clean code, your `field` named `file` should at least be a `property` and the name should reflect what it actually is, so:

```
string file = "";
```

to

```
private string FileFullPath { get; set; }
```

Then the real problem is that you are assigning the full path of the file, including its name to `file`: `file = openFileDialog1.FileName;` but then treating it as a directory `string sourceDir = file;` that should be obvious as to why that would fail... if not... you need to take the full path and just get the directory ie:

```
var sourceDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileFullPath);
```

Comment: This fixed it but the file isn't getting saved in the directory.